# Can ("__proto__" in x) return false ?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a value of param that make this function return true

```
function mustBeTrue(param) {
  return param && !("__proto__" in param);
}
```

My attempt to solve this problem was as follow:
I thought I could just delete the property `__proto__` from any Object and pass it to `param` but it can't get removed.

```
var obj = {foo: 'bar'};

delete obj.foo; //testing delete
console.log('foo' in obj);  //false
delete obj.__proto__
console.log('__proto__' in obj); //true Why ??
```

Comment: Do you know what `__proto__` is? It feels quite normal not being able to delete internal javascript stuff.

Comment: related : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: It's not in your hand, it's reappeareance / impossibility to delete is something builtin the JS engine you are using (would it be the browser's , Node.JS' one, etc...)

Comment: and it's in the EcmaScript standard : https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-additional-properties-of-the-object.prototype-object

Comment: Your question could be rephrased to *"what Javascript value is truthy yet has no `__proto__` (responds negatively to `'__proto__' in`)"*?

Comment: @deceze yes that is my question. I updated the title

Comment: @TSR : which browser / JS engine are you using ? in my devtools console, `__proto__ in {}` returns false (Firefox or Chrome, while Chrome implements the \_\_proto__ accessor.

Comment: @sjahan I was able to delete __proto__ from  an object var o = {} by doing o.__proto__ = null . Please check my answer below

Comment: why tho? why one would one to delete language internal properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research, **it is actually possible** to remove `__proto__` from an Object by setting it to null.

[image]

Comment: So, to be pedantic, you don't actually *remove* \_\_proto__, but you set the binding to null, which is a falsy value, and that's actually solves OP's problem.

Comment: Note that after setting `__proto__` to null you cannot use `Object.prototype`'s methods on that object anymore (i.e. `o.hasOwnProperty('someProperty')`). Also any conversion to string will throw error (because of lack of `toString` method).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Pac0's answer: 
Actually, `'__proto__' in {}` returns `true` in some browsers (IE < 11). 
Currently, all modern browsers have implemented `__proto__` property and it cannot be deleted but it's marked as deprecated, so things may change soon (or may not as it's in standard now).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) (emphasis mine):

> The use of `__proto__` is controversial, and has been discouraged. It was never originally included in the EcmaScript language spec, but modern browsers decided to implement it anyway. Only recently, the `__proto__` property has been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 language specification for web browsers to ensure compatibility, **so will be supported into the future**. It is **deprecated** in favor of `Object.getPrototypeOf/Reflect.getPrototypeOf` and `Object.setPrototypeOf/Reflect.setPrototypeOf`